# How do I keyboard cut and paste in Intern functional test?

Tags: intern

Can someone explain how to perform a keyboard based copy and paste (e.g. CTRL-C, CTRL-V) in an Intern functional test please?

I've navigated to the element using .keys() with the wd.special-keys module but I'm not sure how to actually get a combination key press to work... I've reviewed the documentation at http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/ and the API at https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md but I've been unable to get anything to work.

I've tried using both .keys and .type and tried ending with NULL as I've seen in some WebDriver examples.

For example, should this be expected to work (when an element has focus and text is highlighted)...

```
.type([specialKeys["Control"],"c"])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
.type([wd.SPECIAL_KEYS.Control,"c"])
```

https://github.com/admc/wd/search?q=special_keys